# How to avoid coupling of domain objects with UI data in a store-based Angular app?

Tags: design, state, persistence, clean-architecture, angular

The state of my TypeScript/Angular app contains objects from  the UI layer and from the  business domain layer. I'm exploring   store-based solutions (eg ngrx, ngxs) to keep this state in memory.

As I understand,  such solutions define a single data structure for  both UI and business objects, eg

```
export interface ApplicationState {
uiState: UiState,
domainData: DomainData
}
```

based on [Ngrx Store - An Architecture Guide](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ngrx-store-and-effects-crash-course/).
This data structure is kept in a single store, injected into UI and other components. Data updates due to user inputs are triggered by UI components emitting `actions`. Then,  `reducer` functions change both UI and domain data within  the   `ApplicationState`.

My question is how to use a single-store solution and not end up with     intertwined   UI and business data, and with coupled UI and business layers in general.

- Does combining the `UiState` and  `DomainData` in   `ApplicationState` imply that the two are coupled?
- Does providing a  UI component with the whole state introduce coupling? Why not provide just the UI state or its relevant part?
- Would a solution  with a separate UI store and a Domain store have a cleaner architecture?